# android density independence & sizing issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble getting my application to be scalable to different screen sizes on release.
I read through the support documentation at developer.android.com, Supporting Multiple Screens.

At first the app was just using one size version of images that looked fine on my sony xperia (note. with all height & width set to 'wrap_content'). however when I started trying out the emulated devices (ldpi, hdpi & xhdpi) the sizing was not relating to the display.

Below Are Two examples, the first being the correct view. the size & positioning is as expected
The latter is viewed at xhdpi, or the highest resolution that SDK emulator offers.
the positioning is correct, however the sizing is wrong. (sorry about the screenshot size)

[image: correct view at mdpi]

[image: Incorrect view at xhdpi, emulated]

I took to my editor & created the images again, one for each display type (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) & inserted into the relating resource folders.

I ran the test again, but still had the same sizing issue.

I'm not 100% with this part of android & would appreciate any help or pointers to resolving this issue

p.s please excuse the blanked out sections, they are in place to protect identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the screenshots, a screen with extra high density probably has a very big size (in pixels) so images take a smaller part of the screen. The solution to your problem is to make bigger images for screens with bigger size. From google's Supporting Multiple Screens that you've read you can create a folder like `drawable-normal-mdpi` for screens with normal size, or `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` etc etc

It's not an uncommon problem, just make bigger images for bigger screens, I had this issue when dealing with tablets, there was so much empty space because the screen is so much bigger.

Comment: would I create those additional folders along side the current `drawable-mdpi`? I have already made the images in different sizes (1x, 1.5x, 2x & 3x) and included them in the `drawable-mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` folders

Comment: @SimonAddicott yeah, you have folders like `drawable-mdpi` (and other densities) and if you add `drawable-normal-mdpi` (and other densities) system will check if screen is normal size, then system will pick from these folders else it will go for default (`drawable-mdpi`), I remember there was a page somewhere in android developers site that explains how android selects the right graphics that says it's looking for screen size, language etc etc but I can't find it now